# how to add gradient color to background in div

Tags: html, css

hi i want to add gradient color to my div's background..
I tried this code but it's not working

```css
#apple {
  background: #0E5D7B;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #0E5D7B);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #0E5D7B);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #0E5D7B);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(white, #0E5D7B);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="apple" style="height: 300px;width:auto;background-color:  #0E5D7B; margin-top: 0px;">
</div>
```

please tell me how to fix this

Comment: looks like it is working fine... what is the issue?

Comment: Agree, this works, so what does not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

---

```
#apple{
    height: 300px;
    width:auto;
    background-color:#0E5D7B;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background:linear-gradient(white, lightblue);
}
```

---

```
<div id="apple">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi, you're missing the class selector (a dot). For a class you use a dot, # for an id. Hope this helps